# Calculate Elapsed Time For Each Unit Grouped By Hour

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I'm using SQL Server 2012 (v11.0.7001.0).

I am tasked with calculating automagically the hourly production target for one assembly line. Any guidance is much appreciated, as I am banging my head against a wall.

This assembly line can build a mix of three different units, each with a different takt time to meet demand.

```
Takt Time = Total Available Production Time / Customer Demand
```

The units are produced serially and for each unit produced, a datetime is wrote to a table with the unit number. The takt times are stored in another table.

I am able to query each datetime a unit was produced and that unit's takt time.

```
SELECT 
    p.Timestamp AS ProducedDT, 
    (SELECT TaktTime 
     FROM skutakttime 
     WHERE Material = p.SKU) AS TaktTime 
FROM 
    productionLog p
WHERE 
    p.Timestamp BETWEEN '2022-07-20 06:00:00' 
                    AND (SELECT MAX([Timestamp]) 
                         FROM productionLog 
                         WHERE [CostCenter] = 'Line1' AND [Station] = 3)
    AND [CostCenter] = 'Line1' 
    AND [Station] = 3
```

My query returns this:

```
ProducedDT                  TaktTime
-------------------------------------
2022-07-20 06:17:19.303     98
2022-07-20 06:20:03.507     98
2022-07-20 06:21:31.263     98
2022-07-20 06:23:42.313     98
2022-07-20 06:25:07.040     98
2022-07-20 06:29:38.893     98
2022-07-20 06:31:09.333     98
2022-07-20 06:32:47.533     98
2022-07-20 06:34:19.613     98
2022-07-20 06:35:54.930     98
2022-07-20 06:38:36.850     98
2022-07-20 06:40:17.380     98
2022-07-20 06:41:38.297     98
2022-07-20 06:43:03.930     98
2022-07-20 06:44:39.800     98
2022-07-20 06:46:31.313     98
2022-07-20 06:48:21.487     98
2022-07-20 06:51:25.537     98
2022-07-20 06:53:02.043     98
2022-07-20 06:57:32.623     98
2022-07-20 06:59:02.220     98
2022-07-20 07:00:29.117     98
2022-07-20 07:03:04.730     98
2022-07-20 07:05:33.073     98
2022-07-20 07:07:34.690     98
2022-07-20 07:08:58.740     98
2022-07-20 07:10:25.113     98
2022-07-20 07:11:53.813     98
2022-07-20 07:13:24.540     98
2022-07-20 07:14:44.077     98
2022-07-20 07:16:18.870     98
2022-07-20 07:17:48.630     98
2022-07-20 07:19:21.657     98
2022-07-20 07:21:00.763     98
2022-07-20 07:22:52.070     98
2022-07-20 07:25:28.013     98
2022-07-20 07:27:19.447     98
2022-07-20 07:29:03.943     98
2022-07-20 07:30:39.520     98
2022-07-20 07:32:36.923     98
2022-07-20 07:34:44.183     98
2022-07-20 07:36:16.870     98
2022-07-20 07:37:49.780     98
2022-07-20 07:39:40.923     98
2022-07-20 07:41:33.030     98
2022-07-20 07:43:03.460     98
2022-07-20 07:55:06.543     98
2022-07-20 07:56:50.200     98
2022-07-20 07:58:23.000     98
2022-07-20 08:18:41.510     98
2022-07-20 08:22:47.150     98
2022-07-20 08:24:24.610     98
2022-07-20 08:25:59.843     98
2022-07-20 08:27:35.233     98
2022-07-20 08:29:12.917     98
2022-07-20 08:31:00.070     98
2022-07-20 08:32:44.520     98
2022-07-20 08:34:29.833     98
2022-07-20 08:36:13.337     98
2022-07-20 08:38:33.440     98
2022-07-20 08:40:13.183     98
2022-07-20 08:41:49.987     98
2022-07-20 08:43:29.773     98
2022-07-20 08:45:18.027     98
2022-07-20 08:47:00.277     98
2022-07-20 08:48:48.383     98
2022-07-20 08:50:26.653     98
2022-07-20 08:52:03.557     98
2022-07-20 08:54:06.760     98
2022-07-20 08:55:47.360     98
2022-07-20 08:57:24.213     98
2022-07-20 08:59:09.997     98
2022-07-20 09:00:46.923     98
2022-07-20 09:04:29.803     98
2022-07-20 09:06:06.763     98
2022-07-20 09:07:39.797     98
2022-07-20 09:09:12.967     98
2022-07-20 09:12:56.330     98
2022-07-20 09:14:46.083     98
2022-07-20 09:16:33.160     98
2022-07-20 09:18:27.647     98
2022-07-20 09:20:21.643     98
2022-07-20 09:22:17.887     98
2022-07-20 09:28:53.380     98
2022-07-20 09:31:55.660     98
2022-07-20 10:24:05.053     98
2022-07-20 10:27:41.350     98
2022-07-20 10:29:17.557     98
2022-07-20 10:31:08.093     98
2022-07-20 10:32:33.980     98
2022-07-20 10:34:03.780     98
2022-07-20 10:35:41.880     98
2022-07-20 10:37:23.760     98
2022-07-20 10:39:08.803     98
2022-07-20 10:41:18.667     98
2022-07-20 10:45:44.873     98
2022-07-20 10:47:05.563     98
2022-07-20 10:48:36.183     98
2022-07-20 10:51:30.743     98
2022-07-20 10:52:45.307     98
2022-07-20 10:54:10.483     98
2022-07-20 10:56:47.223     98
2022-07-20 10:58:41.080     98
2022-07-20 10:59:55.767     98
2022-07-20 11:01:10.773     98
2022-07-20 11:03:35.827     98
2022-07-20 11:05:14.577     98
2022-07-20 11:06:36.073     98
2022-07-20 11:08:00.840     98
2022-07-20 11:09:31.973     98
2022-07-20 11:11:19.847     98
2022-07-20 11:12:51.637     98
2022-07-20 11:14:18.457     98
2022-07-20 11:15:44.730     98
2022-07-20 11:22:20.520     98
2022-07-20 11:26:20.517     98
2022-07-20 11:27:43.163     98
2022-07-20 11:30:12.613     98
2022-07-20 11:34:13.937     98
2022-07-20 11:35:48.040     98
2022-07-20 11:37:27.660     98
2022-07-20 11:38:56.573     98
2022-07-20 11:40:22.260     98
2022-07-20 11:41:47.933     98
2022-07-20 11:43:24.913     98
2022-07-20 11:45:15.350     98
2022-07-20 11:46:34.750     98
2022-07-20 11:57:22.407     75
2022-07-20 11:58:54.587     75
2022-07-20 12:33:57.977     75
2022-07-20 12:37:44.883     75
2022-07-20 12:39:19.243     75
2022-07-20 12:40:41.180     75
2022-07-20 12:41:58.140     75
2022-07-20 12:43:26.903     75
2022-07-20 12:45:01.270     75
2022-07-20 12:46:17.687     75
2022-07-20 12:47:35.107     75
2022-07-20 12:51:01.370     75
2022-07-20 12:52:32.433     75
2022-07-20 12:55:19.240     75
2022-07-20 12:56:43.793     75
2022-07-20 12:58:09.890     75
2022-07-20 12:59:30.660     75
2022-07-20 13:00:51.493     75
2022-07-20 13:02:12.290     75
2022-07-20 13:03:34.977     75
2022-07-20 13:04:55.207     75
2022-07-20 13:06:16.070     75
2022-07-20 13:07:44.260     75
2022-07-20 13:09:04.610     75
2022-07-20 13:10:31.490     75
2022-07-20 13:16:50.060     75
2022-07-20 13:18:22.540     75
2022-07-20 13:20:08.420     75
2022-07-20 13:21:24.263     75
2022-07-20 13:22:54.507     75
2022-07-20 13:24:16.277     75
2022-07-20 13:25:34.363     75
2022-07-20 13:27:52.450     85
2022-07-20 13:29:27.670     85
2022-07-20 13:30:57.497     85
2022-07-20 13:33:51.703     85
2022-07-20 13:35:18.760     85
2022-07-20 13:36:46.613     85
2022-07-20 13:38:12.270     85
2022-07-20 13:39:39.317     85
2022-07-20 13:41:17.830     85
2022-07-20 13:42:34.783     85
2022-07-20 13:44:07.710     85
2022-07-20 13:45:37.210     85
2022-07-20 13:47:04.050     85
2022-07-20 13:48:24.860     85
2022-07-20 13:50:00.310     85
2022-07-20 13:51:21.963     85
2022-07-20 13:53:10.090     85
2022-07-20 13:54:33.530     85
2022-07-20 13:55:54.050     85
2022-07-20 13:57:18.107     85
2022-07-20 13:58:58.043     85
2022-07-20 14:00:17.117     85
2022-07-20 14:01:40.283     85
2022-07-20 14:03:09.720     85
2022-07-20 14:05:20.477     85
2022-07-20 14:07:15.293     85
2022-07-20 14:08:50.077     85
2022-07-20 14:10:22.320     85
2022-07-20 14:12:05.843     85
```

To complicate things more, I am to calculate the target between distinct time blocks.

```
1 - 6:00 to 7:00
2 - 7:00 to 8:00
3 - 8:15 to 9:00
4 - 9:00 to 10:00
5 - 10:15 to 11:00
6 - 11:00 to 12:00
7 - 12:30 to 13:30
8 - 13:30 to 14:30
9 - 14:45 to 15:30
10 - 15:30 to 16:30
```

Calculation Example From Block 6.

I am leaving the decimal point in place until I am told whether to round up or down.

```
11:00:00 - 11:46:34 Ran 23 units      
- Run Time 2794s / 98s Takt Time = 28.52 Units Should Have Been Produced  

11:46:34 - 12:00:00 Ran 2 units     
- Run Time 806s / 75s Takt Time = 10.74 Units Should Have Been Produced 

- Target For Block 6 = 39.26 Units
```

Expected Result *Corrected Group 7 & 8

```
TimeBlock       Target
----------------------
1               36.73
2               36.73
3               27.55
4               36.73
5               27.55
6               39.25
7               47.58
8               42.35
9               0
10              0
```

I have a stored procedure already that gets the total produced per time block, average actual cycle time between entries, and calculates performance based on actual cycle time vs target. However, I am having a hard time visualizing a way to do this in SQL.

Comment: I'm missing something. Where do the run times (in your example, 2795 and 806) come from?

Comment: Nevermind - it's the number of seconds in the interval. I have everything I need and just need to incorporate that into an answer.

Comment: Can you show how do you calculate ` Run Time 2795s`?

Comment: @Squirrel - `select datediff(second, '11:00:00', '11:46:34')`.

Comment: `select datediff(second, '11:00:00', '11:46:34') = 2794`  not `2795` as what you have stated in the question

Comment: I'm attributing it to a fencepost error to which the typical remedy is "add one"

Comment: Or, alternatively, state why you think that the fencepost error is a logic error (as I intend to do in my writeup)

Comment: @Seth-Johnson - can you double-check your calculations for groups 7 & 8? I've got a query that produces the first six just fine, but those two are off. For the penultimate calculation for group 7, I get a time range 12:30:00-13:25:34 for TaktTime 75 and 13:25:34 -13:30:00 for TaktTime 85. Using what I think is the formula gives me (3334/75) + (266/85) = 47.58.

Comment: @Ben Thule - I apologize, that is my mistake. You are correct that group 7 should be 47.58. Group 8 is also wrong and should be 42.35.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I hope you have the `time block` information in a table. You can then join to it and make the grouping easier.

The query uses window function `lead()` or `lag()` to group those rows with same `TaktTime` together as a group `Grp`

After `Grp` information is available, next is to get the first `ProducedDT` and last `ProducedDT` of the group to calculate the `datediff()` in seconds. However, for your requirement, it is not simply that way. It might be the start  or end time of the time block. That is what the CTE `cte` is doing. `start_tm` and `end_tm` is the start and end time used for calculation

CTE `pl` consists of other value of the Produced Date & Time to make subsequent calculation and comparison of date and time easier. `ProducedD` is converted back to `datetime` instead of just `date` to save some typing futher on when need to add a date and a time together.

On `start_tm`, use the `time_block.time_start` instead of it's own `ProducedDT` when it is the first row of the time block (`lag(ProducedDT)` will be `NULL`).

On `end_tm`, when it is the last row of the time block (`lead(ProducedDT)` will be `NULL`) then use it's own `ProducedDT`. Otherwise use the `time_block.time_end`

Actually both may use the same `CASE` syntax instead of `CASE` and `COLAESCE`. I was just being lazy :)

---

The solution is based on following table schema.

```
create table productionLog 
(
    ProducedDT  datetime,
    TaktTime    int
);

create table time_block
(
    id          int,
    time_start  time(0),
    time_end    time(0)
);
```

The query

```
with pl as
(
    select  ProducedDT, 
            ProducedD = convert(datetime, convert(date, ProducedDT)),
            ProducedT = convert(time(0), ProducedDT),
            TaktTime, 
            g   = case  when TaktTime
                        <>   lag(TaktTime) over (order by ProducedDT)
                        then 1
                        else 0
                        end
    from    productionLog 
),
cte as
(
    select  *,
            start_tm    = coalesce(lag(ProducedDT) over (partition by pl.ProducedD, tb.id
                                                             order by pl.ProducedDT),
                                   pl.ProducedD + convert(datetime, tb.time_start)),
            end_tm      = case  when lead(ProducedDT) over (partition by pl.ProducedD, tb.id
                                                                order by pl.ProducedDT) is not null
                                then ProducedDT
                                else pl.ProducedD + convert(datetime, tb.time_end)
                                end
    from    (
                select  ProducedDT, ProducedD, ProducedT, TaktTime,
                        Grp = sum(g) over (order by ProducedDT)
                from    pl
            ) pl
            inner join time_block tb    on  tb.time_start   <= pl.ProducedT
                                       and  tb.time_end >  pl.ProducedT
)
select  ProducedD, id, sum(Diff * 1.0 / TaktTime)
from
(
    select  ProducedD, id, TaktTime, Grp, 
            Diff = datediff(second, min(start_tm), max(end_tm))
    from    cte
    group by ProducedD, id, TaktTime, Grp
) t
group by ProducedD, id;
```

[db<>fiddle demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=3ae0158a6a947ae96f5620a3f71fcb23)

Comment: Thank you very much, Squirrel! I had forgotten about cte's, and I never would have thought of using two of them. One querying the other like you did. So this works by first creating cte "pl" that gets the dt from productionLog, separates the date and time into two columns, and grabs the takttime. Then sets g to 1 (true) if the previous TaktTime is not equal. Essentially detecting when takttime changes. The next cte is a bit fuzzy for me. start_tm in particular. end_tm checks the next dt is valid and returns that dt, else returns the end time of the group.

Comment: I will need to add another constraint to the query to get the times from the time_block. There are many lines and naturally, they have different time blocks. I just need to add the line number into the query to only get the time blocks for a particular line. Also, I will eventually need to expand this to cover third shift and passing midnight.

Comment: OR, just had a thought...leave this query intact and add another CTE at the beginning using my original query to get only the log for the line I need?

Comment: You can just modify the CTE `pl` and add any `WHERE` condition that you need or add another CTE in front. Both way, are the same